# catfish has swollen belly

Tags: fish

I have some catfish, I noticed a few a them have swollen bellies, maybe 10 in 1000 have these swollen and reddish bellies, not sure if it's something to be worried about.

also they are like this before feeding in the morning, the belly never goes down

I'd share some pictures, please let me know if you've experienced similar

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do they all swim with the belly up? Or is it for the picture only? Looks like a problem with gas - either in the "belly" or with the swim bladder...

Comment: sometimes they swim with the belly up, but most times they swim normally, they only face up sometimes when restingm alright yeah, cause when i pressed on the belly, it just seemed like a pocket of air

Comment: i was told it's caused by overfeeding from a friendm although i doubt that

Comment: Swollen belly for no good reason is a sure sign of illness. Talk to a vet

Comment: If any don't look like they are going to survive, considering you have thousands, I would euthanize one and do an autopsy on it. See if you're dealing with air, food, or parasites, or something else. With that much swelling, I imagine it's going to be obvious, then you can actually diagnose and treat it.

I'm going to guess the color is likely from inflammation, the bulge is the real problem here.

And, no I typically don't suggest killing a live animal as a method of diagnosis, but if it's contagious, you could lose more and guessing/shotgun approaches to treatments almost never work.

Comment: Probably worms if I had to guess